# Is there an online IPv6 <-> IPv4 translator out there some where?

Tags: web-apps, networking

I am looking for an online tool that can translate IPv6 to IPv4 addresses and vice versa.

Is there one out there some where?

Comment: Are you talking about some kind gateway to tunnel the packets?  The addresses cannot be translated in both directions (IPv4 can be represented in IPv6, not not necessarily vice-versa).

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_transition_mechanism for a discussion of some of the mechanisms available.

Comment: I mean a software utility that when presented with an IP address will convert it to the other IP address's format, so long as it is a valid range, meaning something that can convert the whole IPv4 range to IPv6 but no vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer is **No** there is not - this is because while some IPv6 addresses can be mapped to an IPv4 address automatically and vice versa for the vast majority of IPv6 addresses there is no possible direct equivalent.

This is because the IPv6 addresses outnumber IPv4 addresses by about 790,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 (7.9E28) to 1 so it is a bit like asking for a unique two way mapping between beaches and grains of sand.

Windows machines allow the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses to be set individually for each network adapter.  There are some address ranges that are reserved for automatic mapping such as 255.0.a.b.c.d <=> a.b.c.d in Stateless IP/ICMP Translation and there are several other tunnelling mechanisms most of which rely on having known mappings.  See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_transition_mechanism) for more information.

Comment: How about one which works with IPv4 ranges only, in both directions, ie translate IPv4 to IPv6 and IPv6 to IPv4 so long as the IPv6 is in the right range.

Comment: Not that is sure to work - Stateless translation provides a simple rule: 255.0.a.b.c.d => a.b.c.d & a.b.c.d => 255.0.a.b.c.d but only if the network is configured to handle traffic that way.